# How can i resolve System.String IdentityModel.CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(Int32)

Tags: c#, token, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I want to create token with `IdentityServer4` but when I add this line :

```
services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() <------ EXCEPTION
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
```

in my project I have this exception

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.String IdentityModel.CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(Int32)'.'

I add to have the line `.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` to my project because previously when i run my api to see my token I have this error :

> "Keyset is missing"

When I wanted to run my api.

I follow [this](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) to create my project.

Comment: Did you update the package for the IdentityServer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `IdentityServer` works in my case. You find lastest version [here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/)

Comment: This worked probably because you were referencing a project that was using a newer dependency than what was compatible for the version of IdentityServer you were using. Upgrading IdentityServer just aligned the dependency versions

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem, and this was the cause:

If you are running IdentityServer4, version 2.5.4 or lower, and you reference a project that contains IdentityModel, version 4.0.0 or higher, you will get this error.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -3):

Did you do like this?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()....
```

And u need to restart the client every time you try to test it.
The client makes a call only once per session